# How to embed Youtube & Vimeo videos in Sitecore JSS with React

Tags: jss, react, sitecore-react

I have create a video player component in Sitecore jss/react.  I have tried with `react-player` player plugin. It is working fine in disconnected mode but as soon as I deployed it in Sitecore, it is neither working in Sitecore Experience Editor nor on live site.

Is it possible to video component in Sitecore jss/react?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a video component without using any react plugin. It supports both Youtube and Vimeo. The code snippet is very small. Please see below

```
<iframe
  width="100%"
  height="345"
  title="event-video"
  src={videoUrl}
/>
```

Here I retrieve the `videoUrl` from Sitecore Item which should be of the embedding type. You can also retrieve the `videoUrl` from a GraphQL. Below are examples of the urls

*Youtube*

https://www.youtube.com/embed/1YuN3POoNnQ

*Vimeo*

https://player.vimeo.com/video/421689971

To get the Embedded URL, you can retrieve it by clicking on Share button and then select the embed part. See screenshot below

[image]

Comment: thanks for your  help, it has saved my time.

Comment: @amitkumar since it helped can you please upvote and approve the answer so that it benefits others also